# give runtime sms permission error in android

Tags: android, sms

I am trying to sending a message from device but whenever i am sending message from app it gives SEND sms permission error..
it gives this error...id 10281 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS.
 i am trying following code.

```
public void fetch(String cstfrom, String msg) {
    //Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " where Category = '" +categoryex + "'" , null);
    String query = "SELECT mobile FROM employee WHERE empcst ='" + cstfrom + "' ";
    database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        itemname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("mobile"));
        Toast.makeText(this, itemname, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
               == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

                Log.d("permission", "permission denied to SEND_SMS - requesting it");
                String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS};

                requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                sms.sendTextMessage(itemname, null, "hiii", null, null);

            }
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: and i guess the permission dialog is also not showing up ? is it and also post the complete code

Comment: no dialog box is shown

Comment: one ideal way would be asking permissions before executing your current code , in current case , you don't have permission but still executing the sms code , hence crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include this in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you edited your Manifest.xml file?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.roa.sendsms"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is not a correct way of handling permissions. I have made a helper library which, I think, will make it easier for you. 
Instructions: https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions

Comment: Don't use this library becuase it is wrong ... it cause memory leak and doesn't work with "Don't keep activities"

Comment: No it does not cause memory leak as I have nullified the static reference before the callback is called.

Comment: It leaks Activity ... as handler may live longer than Activity which is referenced in it [this is similar situation to this](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)